# How to set Cookie offset in URP Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/light-component.html#LightCookie) in manual we see described text about cookie offset "**You can also animate this property to scroll the cookie**" :

[image]

Here in Editor i can change the offset in runtime:

[image]

But how to do this from script if he tells me this:

> 'Light' does not contain a definition for 'cookieOffset' and no accessible extension method 'cookieOffset' accepting a first argument of type 'Light' could be found

Answer (score 0):

Use URP extantion UniversalAdditionalLightData instead

```
public class LightCookieDisplacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private UniversalAdditionalLightData lightExtantion;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lightExtantion = GetComponent<UniversalAdditionalLightData>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        lightExtantion.lightCookieOffset += Vector2.one * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```